# Store Data in TPM using CNG NCryptOpenStorageProvider in Windows

Tags: c++, cng, tpm

I am trying to store the key in TPM using CNG NCryptOpenStorageProvide "MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER".

Please any one help on How to use CNG functions for accessing TPM read and Write.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "store a key in TPM" you mean "create a persisted key in the TPM":

```
NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProv = NULL;
NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
PCWSTR keyName = L"MyKey";

NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
        &hProv,
        MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER,
        0);
NCryptCreatePersistedKey(
        hProv,
        &hKey,
        BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,
        keyName,
        0,
        NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG);
NCryptFinalizeKey(hKey, 0);
```

Obviously you should check the return code of each invoked function.